# Android: Not able to move the cursor along text on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multiline edittext field. I can write everything but when I try to go back and put the cursor on a given position I am not able to do it. Instead the cursor goes to the start of the text and never moves from there again.

NOTE; My text is only one long 'word'. A sequence of HEX characters.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what device are you using?

Comment: I am using ICS on a custom device. TI-processor.

Comment: Does the cursor have a little tumb tab underneath it that lets you drag it around? Also if you run the same code on a stock device do you get the same issue? If not I would suspect the issue is with the EditText code that is inside the OS build on your specific device.

Comment: Please, share your code. Because edit text gives default property of selecting cursor to any position. It may be due to any fancy thing your doing, So it will be clear if you share your code. I does it on Nexus 10(4.2.2) and on Nexus 7(4.1.2) works fine. This may not be the version issue.